# Como pegar o primeiro e último dia do mês atual ? PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, pessoal.

Eu gostaria de pegar o primeiro e o último dia do mês atual e armazená-los em duas variáveis para usá-las em uma condição de uma consulta de uma query no MYSQL.

Vocês conhecem uma forma de realizar isso ?

Desde já, agradeço. 
Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem uma forma que aqui será apresentada de forma bastante genérica, porém útil, que segue abaixo:

```
<?php
// Definir a zona geográfica padrão.
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");

// Pegar o último dia.
$P_Dia = date("Y-m-01");
$U_Dia = date("Y-m-t");

print "Teste de Data Inicial :: " . $P_Dia . "<br>";
print "Teste de Data Final :: " . $U_Dia . "<br>";

// Inicializar conexão PDO.
$DSN = "mysql:127.0.0.1/Database";
$Username = "root";
$Password = "123456";
// Inicilizar conexão.
$Connect = new PDO($DSN, $Username, $Password) or die(NULL);

// Preparar transação.
$Statement = $Connect->prepare("
    SELECT
       Campo1,
       Campo2,
       CampoN
    FROM MinhaTabela
    WHERE DataInicio = :DataI
      AND DataFim = :DataF");

$Statement->bindParam(":DaiaI", $P_Dia);
$Statement->bindParam(":DataF", $U_Dia);
$Statement->execute();

// Segue o fluxo de tratamento...
?>
```

Quealquer coisa comenta que ajusto algo que faltar.

Comment: Fala ai, @Luis Alberto. Pelo que pude ver, vc está usando PDO. Eu uso mysqli. Mas vou tentar ver se ajusto seu código de acordo com o meu.

Comment: Reparei que no date você utilizou o "t". Pra que serviria esse "t" ?

Comment: Para pegar o último dia do mês.

Comment: Beleza, Luis. Deu certo aqui. Obrigado!